Can we import a python made ML model (.pkl) in rust?
I was building a project in Python, but since it was taking too much resources and lack concurrency I shifted to rust. Now I am confused on how to properly migrate it, most of the code has been migrated but I cannot import the ml model that was exported as .pkl file.

What sort of Python objects does the pickle file contain?

Your .pkl file is likely a python pickle. You should be able to use serde_pickle to deserialize it.
